# Compare a single row with a column and extract the value from another column on the same row in Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement

So I'm looking for a formula or anything that does something like this:

I have 4 Columns. A B C D.

I have a column (A) with multiple values that can have duplicates.

```
A1: A
A2: A
A3: B
A4: C
A5: C
```

I want to compare each row with a Column (B) that has one of each value. So B1 = A, B2 = B etc.
However the value I want to extract to column "D" is in Column "C". So if A1 equals anything in the Column B, I want to extract the value in Column C on the same row, to Column D.

So in D1 I want the value from C1. In D2 I want the value from C1 as well. But in D3 I want the value from C2.

Comment: Please show your current work. What did you do so far and where are the problems? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

`=VLOOKUP(A1:A5,B1:C5,2,0)`

Entered as *Array Formula* in D1:D5 using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

**Result:**
[image]

Comment: Seems like I have a different type of Excel since mine uses ; instead of , to separate the different parameters. However, I wrote this formula (Note that I have Swedish, but I'll explain.)

=LETAUPP(H2:H3599;K2:L311;2)

Where LETAUPP is LOOKUP. I did also do it as an Array Formula. The value 2 as the last parameter seems to be the problem, what does it stand for and what is it?

Comment: @user3769964 No problem on comma(,) or semi-colon(;). We just have different default separator. For the translation of VLOOKUP see [here](http://en.excel-translator.de/vlookup/). Based from there, you can try `=LETARAD(A1:A5,B1:C5,2,0)`.